# Problem with Rust installing firebase-admin on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, rust, pip, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install firebase-admin on a Raspberry Pi 4 B (to upload stuff to firestore) with:

`pip3 install firebase-admin`

,but im always getting the error:

`error: can't find Rust compiler

...

### This package requires Rust >=1.48.0.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
`

Of course I rebooted the devide, tried it with sudo and tried
`sudo apt update sudo apt upgrade` 
before I tried it again.
I also tried to install rust manually with:
`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh source $HOME/.cargo/env` 
wich went successful but
`rustc --version` 
always gave me the error:
`error: command failed: 'rustc': No such file or directory (os error 2)`
why I think there is a problem acessing the rust installation.

Im relative new to these topics. Do you have any Idea, where the Problem could be?